# Are the contents of 'methods' option on Active Model's 'as_json' method ignored when undefined?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, activerecord

I have a model `model`, and am trying to render that with `as_json`. I am calling the `:methods` option on it like this:

```
model.as_json(methods: [:foo, :bar])
```

The output includes a key-value pair for the method `foo`, but not for `bar`. It might be the case that `bar` is not defined correctly while `foo` is not, I am not sure.

In such case, would `as_json` silently ignore the application of the undefined methods? If so, is there a way to be notified by an error? Or, could there be any other reason that particular key-value pairs become silently ignored from the `as_json` output?

I am using Active Model 4.2.7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In such case, would `as_json` silently ignore the application of the undefined methods?

Yes in older versions of active model, and no since a certain version. To be more precise with older versions of active model, it is not the case that undefined methods are ignored; what are ignored are methods that do not return a truthy value to `respond_to?`. In the code at: `https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activemodel/lib/active_model/serialization.rb`, there used to be a line:

```
Array(options[:methods]).each { |m| hash[m.to_s] = send(m) if respond_to?(m) }
```

where `hash` is the output of this method. Methods specified by the `:methods` option were ignored when they did not respond. However, [this change](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/b2967999aeb424d219393f2e01e88a92f37a78c3) altered [the corresponding line](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activemodel/lib/active_model/serialization.rb#L137) into:

```
Array(options[:methods]).each { |m| hash[m.to_s] = send(m) }
```

which raises a method missing error when the method is not defined.

> If so, is there a way to be notified by an error?

The easiest way is to update the active model to at least later than the commit mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

An option is override `as_json` method in your model. Here you have to check if the methods are available in your model, if the method is not defined, remove it from options and do some notify action. This way the not available methods will be ignored.

An approximation code would be

```
class Model < ApplicationRecord

  def as_json(options = {})

    if options.key? :methods
      if options[:methods].is_a? Array
        methods_copy = options[:methods].clone
        methods_copy.each do |opt|
          if !self.respond_to? opt
            # do notify, log, etc
            options[:methods].delete opt
          end
        end
      elsif options[:methods].is_a? Symbol
        if !self.respond_to? options[:methods]
          # do notify, log, etc
          options.delete :methods
        end
      else
        # do some actions here
      end
    end

    super(options)
  end
end
```

Then call `as_json` as usual

```
model.as_json(methods: [:foo, :bar])
```

**UPDATE**

As I misread the question, here an update based on the answer of @sawa

Older versions of ActiveModel don't notify when some method is not defined when `methods` options is passed.

Upgrading the above code

```
def as_json(options = {})
  Array(options[:methods]).each do |m|
    raise "method #{m} doesn't exists" if !self.respond_to?(m)
  end
  super(options)
end
```

Comment: That is the opposite of what I am asking.

Comment: oh! you are right! In this case if you are using older versions (and you cannot update AR), you have to check with `respond_to?` and raise an exception or whatever

Answer (score 1):

Methods included in `as_json` must be public methods. If `bar` is a private method, it will not be included.

This situation is a subset of the `responds_to?`issue mentioned in [@sawa's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42687953/2691039), and is probably resolved by the same commit linked in the answer.

Comment: Good point. That is a special case of response to `respond_to?`.

Comment: Yep. Will modify answer to loop back to your answer.